# How do I use Web Component of MIT App Inventor in Android Studio?

Tags: android, app-inventor, mobile-development

- I have made an Application in MIT App Inventor for sending GET request for connecting to WiFi Module [ ESP8266 ].
- There is a button which when clicked sets the Web URL to ESP8266's IP address, for example http://192.168.4.1/?pin=13
- Then a function call on Web is used and a GET request is send.
- I wanted to ask how to implement the same functionality using Android Studio. Maybe a name of component or function in Java Code.
- I am attaching the block design  for reference.
  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this site:
http://www.appinventor.org/jBridgeIntro

The library file (http://www.appinventor.org/javaBridge/downloads/AppInventor-JavaLibrary.jar) can be added as a library file for your project.

You then get all the 'blocks' as in AppInventor, but they're pre-prepared Java classess etc.

Comment: It worked out with App Inventor Java bridge.Maybe because it is in a beta stage, some of the function calls and part of code is missing, the following statements had to be written in order for achieving the same functionality :  Web1.Get() ; /* function call missing in android studio */, also <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"> /* had to be added in AndroidManifest.xml */